# Can we avoid navigating to Azure Ad login screen when we configure SSO with Azure AD as ID provider

Tags: single-sign-on, authentication, auth-provider, open-id-connect, azure

I have to configure Single Sign using Azure AD for our salesforce community as Identity provider and Salesforce being the service provider, I want to use Open id Connect.

I want check with the forum if there is a way we can avoid users navigation to Azure AD screen to provide there user id details.  Is there a way to customise this experience so that users have to never navigate away from Salesforce pages.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Out of the box - no. You can roll your own custom login and other pages that have more of an "inline" experience where it may appear that the user does not navigate "away" from the page.